# PIG UDF import resolve

Tags: java, apache-pig

New to UDFs. Borrowed another post as template, but not the same cause I think
`ERROR 1070: Could not resolve myudfs.UPPER using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]`

### Script

```
register /home/tad/pig/myudf.jar;
quantiles = LOAD '/user/tad/quantiles' using PigStorage('\t','-schema');
--just one line of data
a = foreach quantiles generate 'a';
b = foreach a generate myudfs.UPPER($0);
```

### Function

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class UPPER extends EvalFunc<String>
{
  public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
      if (input == null || input.size() == 0 || input.get(0) == null)
          return null;
      try{
          String str = (String)input.get(0);
         return str.toUpperCase();
      }catch(Exception e){
          throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
      }
  }
}
```

It doesn't report error when register, which mean pig finds the jar file okay.

Run from Grunt

### Structure of jar

```
META-INF
myudf
 +--UPPER.java
 +--IndexOfBig.java
 +--IndexOfBig.class
 +--pig.jar
 +--UPPER.class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no package in your jar structure, you can add it or remove it from script.

1- Adding package structure (no need for `pig.jar` here):

```
myudfs
  +-- UPPER.java
  +-- IndexOfBig.java
  +-- IndexOfBig.class
  +-- UPPER.class
```

2- Or remove it from code and script and keep the jar as it is:

**Script**

```
b = foreach a generate UPPER($0);
```

**Function**

```
//package myudfs; // remove this line
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class UPPER extends EvalFunc<String>
{
 ..
```

If the jar is in local file system:

```
register /localpath/tad/pig/myudf.jar;
```

If its in the hdfs:

```
register hdfs://namenode:port/tad/pig/myudf.jar;
```

And finally, depending to your build tool, the manifest attributes may be not set to work properly as a pig udf, to get rid of that, easily package your `class` files in a jar file using the command line with this command:

```
jar cf myjar IndexOfBig.class UPPER.class
```

Comment: I see. I have the jar file as myudf +-- .class and .java files. the myudf is in the same dir with the META-INF folder.